# Array of Numbers can be seen in the logs of both frontend and backend yet it is not saved in the database

Tags: javascript, angular, mongoose, mongoose-schema

**I am trying to replicate google's Backup Codes system by generating 4 random 8 digit numbers.**

```
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      let backendCode = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99999999 - 10000000 + 1) + 10000000);
      backendCodes.push(backendCode);
    }
```

**Using a Backend Service to post to the backend.**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  signUpUser(email: string, password: string, backendCodes: number[]) {
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/signup/api"
    const body = { email, password, backendCodes };
    console.log(body); // Add this line to log the request body
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    this.http.post(url, body, { headers }).subscribe({
      next: value => console.log(value),
      error: error => console.log(error),
      complete: () => console.log("Complete")
    });
  }
```

**Then saving it in the database (MongoDB).**

```
app.post("/signup/api", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, backupCodes } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body); 
  try {
    const newUser = new User({
      email: email,
      password: password,
      backupCodes: backupCodes,
    });

    await newUser.save();
    console.log("Successful");
    res.status(200).json({ message: "User signed up successfully" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error: ", err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});
```

## What was I expecting

I was expecting everything to be saved, but saw that the backupCodes was empty.
[As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQepI.png)

## What I've tried

I tried logging the output before posting to the backend and before saving the data to the database

**Frontend**

```
signUpUser(email: string, password: string, backendCodes: number[]) {
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/signup/api"
    const body = { email, password, backendCodes };

    console.log(body); // Test before post

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    this.http.post(url, body, { headers }).subscribe({
      next: value => console.log(value),
      error: error => console.log(error),
      complete: () => console.log("Complete")
    });
  }
```

**Backend**

```
app.post("/signup/api", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, backupCodes } = req.body;

  console.log(req.body); // Test before saving to Database

  try {
    const newUser = new User({
      email: email,
      password: password,
      backupCodes: backupCodes,
    });

    await newUser.save();
    console.log("Successful");
    res.status(200).json({ message: "User signed up successfully" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error: ", err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});
```

**Here is the screenshots of the result:-**

[Frontend Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6lUC.png) and
[Backend Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/210sD.png)

**Here is my Schema, if this is the issue:**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  backupCodes: [Number],
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array property is named **backupCodes** in your schema but your console logs show the property name is **backendCodes**.

Comment: *Sigh,* this was the mistake... The only mistake that stopped it from storing the backup codes. I wonder if this has happened to you or others.

Comment: Afraid so.  : )  I'm a .NET guy and the model binding in MVC is a huge timesaver until you misname something and spend all day troubleshooting everything but the spelling of the property names.

Comment: Is there something similar for web development? It would be 2nd nicest thing because the first is ChatGPT /s

Comment: Yes, the modelbinder is part of asp.net MVC (which is web development).  It allows you to automatically bind the incoming object (JSON in my case, but also submitted forms) to a DTO you define to handle the incoming data in the Controller method.  You could check it out here if you're up for a new angle of development.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0